# Regression model produces low coefficient but high R-squared?

Tags: r, linear-regression, transformation, survey

I'm doing research on right wing radicalization factors. Since I'm using survey data and have to account for oversampling, I'm using the `survey`-package. Furthermore I log-transformed the dependent variable in order to adjust for its right skewed distribution. This are the relevant code lines:

```
dat_wght <- svydesign(ids= ~1, data=dat, weights =~wghtpew)

mod1 <-svyglm(log(right) ~ religiosity, design = dat_wght)
```

For model 1, I get this regression output:

```
Call:
svyglm(formula = log(right) ~ religiosity, 
    design = dat_wght)

Survey design:
svydesign(ids = ~1, data = dat, weights = ~wghtpew)

Coefficients:
                                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                     2.493398   0.016111 154.763  < 2e-16 ***
religiosity                     0.016750   0.004091   4.094 4.43e-05 ***
```

Since it is a log-model, I interpretated the coefficient as follows: If independent variable religiosity increases by 1 unit, the dependent variable right increases by `(exp(0.01675)-1)*100=1.69%.` This would mean that there is indeed some kind of correlation, but the effect is very very low. Is that correct so far?

Furthermore, I want to calculate R-squared. The svyglm-model doesn't provide R-squared immediately. However you guys kindly pointed out, that I can calculate it by myself with:

```
total_var <-svyvar(~right, dat_wght)
resid_var_mod1 <- summary(mod1)$dispersion
rsq_mod1 <- 1-resid_var_mod1/total_var
rsq_mod1
```

However, the result I get is:

```
        variance    SE
right   0.99407 0.0028
```

How can that be? If the effect is very very low, my model apparently isn't suited to explain the variation in the dependent variable. Therefore R-squared should also be very low and much closer to zero than to 1, shouldn't it? Why is it so high then? Did I interpretate my coefficients wrong? Are there any mistakes that I did along the way?

I'm really grateful for every kind of advice! Thanks :)

Comment: Not a programming question. I did the "let me search SE for you" maneuver with the title of your question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Regression+model+produces+low+coefficient+but+high+R-squared%3F

Comment: @IRTFM I'm really sorry, but I don't get it. Can you tell me which post exactly deals with the same problem as I have and provides an answer to my question?

Comment: I don't see why the size of the coefficient and R-squared would necessarily be related. For example you could just use a scaled version of the covariate, `religiosity = religiosity / 1000`, and you'd have the exact same R-squared, but a 1000x larger coefficient.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Oh okay.. From how I understood it: R-squared is the ratio of residual variation to total variation or in other words: How much of the variation in the dependent variable can be explained by the variation in the independent variable. Therefore I thought that, if my independent variable religiosity has no great effect on the dependent variable, it can not explain the variation in the dependent variable (cause that what "it has no effect means)...and therefore my R-squared should be way lower.. still trying to wrap my head around this..

Comment: But nevertheless,  if it's that close to 1, I think something has to be wrong..

Comment: Still not a programming question. If you have not gotten an answer from the stats.SE.com Q&A's then my providing a link to where you _SHOULD_ have posted in the first place should have been an adequate hint that such questions belong elsewhere. You can still flag your own question and as that it be migrated.

Comment: @IRTFM Sorry. I've flagged the question. But yes, indeed: A super adequate and obvious hint for someone who's a) new to the forum, b) new to the subject and actually ASKED if it might be a programming error or not and c) not a native english speaker. So thanks for your kind help.

Comment: What units is `religiosity` in? What is its range?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's simpler than everyone thought. Your R^2 calculation is just wrong.

You compute the residual variance of `log(right)` and divide it by the population variance of `right`. You need to use the population variance of `log(right)` as well.